# ofxCv name must be a namespace

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, openframeworks

I'm trying to add openframeworks to Visual C++ project. I do not have any problems adding headers. I can include them with no error. However, when I add

```
using namespace ofxCv;
```

I get a titled error. I've also added the plugin mentioned [here](https://openframeworks.cc/setup/vs/). Why is that happening? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use `using namespace` anyway.

Comment: @FeiXiang what should i use? the code i've includes that line.

Comment: Namespaces are there for a reason. You should just do `ofxCv::` every time you use something from that header.